# Optimize select in statement

Tags: mysql

Can anybody help me to optimize the below query? This query does a full table scan. I want to avoid the full table scan. Both the tables has indexs for startdate and enddate

```
select sr.id, sr.serviceTypeId,  sr.petLocationId  
  from ServiceRule sr
  where   (sr.startDate<=1443312000 and (sr.endDate>=1434067200 or sr.endDate=0)) 
  or (sr.id in (select distinct serviceRuleId from ServiceException 
  where (startDate>=1434096000 and startDate<=1443340800) 
  or (startDate<1434096000 and (endDate between 1434096000 and 1443340800)) 
  or (startDate<1434096000 and endDate>1443340800) 
or ((1434096000 between startDate and endDate) and (1443340800 between startDate and endDate))))
```

[image]

tried using joins. the execution time is below 1 sec.

Comment: Try to get a condition without OR clause for index use.

Comment: How long does the query take without the `in` condition?

Comment: @ZafarMalik : there is no other condition that i can use..is the full table scan happening as the query has only OR clause in where condition?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: without in, it take 0.042 seconds

Comment: basically there should be at least one condition which can filter data but your all conditions are linked with OR clause....further you can check query performance with following 2 approaches -- 1. remove in cluase and  use of join....2. remove OR clause and join 2 queries with union clause..compare query performance with all 3 methods (1 yourself and 2 as suggested by me) and go with best one for you.

Comment: @ZafarMalik :  okay..i will do the same..